# Windows Forms graph freezes when the title bar is clicked

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-forms-designer

I created a Windows Forms application (C#, .NET Framework 4.5) that graphs the data received via the serial line (ex. a sensor attached to a microcontroller). For the graphing I am using ZedGraph library. The problem I ran into is that if I click on the titlebar when the data is being received and plotted, the graph freezes for the duration of the click. As soon as I release the left mouse button, it normally continues the plotting, except that it now just connects the data point received right before the click with the one received right after the mouse button was released. An example is shown below:

[image]

This seems to happen only with the graphing part, since the program also outputs the received data to a file. If I plot the received data in another program after the measurement (Excel, Matlab, ...), all the data is as it should be, without any interruptions.

I tried to find what the reason might be, but I could not find a similar example anywhere, so any help would be appreciated.

In order to simplify the process of finding the solution I have also created a smaller program that simply prints the time from the stopwatch to a textBox. Here is the code:

```
namespace ClickFreezeTest
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => updateTextBox());
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void updateTextBox()
    {
        Stopwatch myStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        myStopWatch.Start();
        int a = 1;
        while (a == 1)
        {
            textBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(myStopWatch.Elapsed); }));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The form looks like this:

[image]

As shown in the code above, the textBox is updated every 100 ms on a separate thread. The same problem appears as with the serial graphing program, so I am assuming that if the solution exists it has to do something with the form settings, maybe a control that allows the user to do something with the mouse.

Comment: You could cache the values in a list, and only perform the drawing once the mouse button has been released ... eg save the data points that are recorded during the mouse down event, and then output them all in one go once the button is released. Kind of feels like there's an issue with mouse down blocking the UI thread, but the technique I've just outlined should still work.

Comment: Thank you! If I understand right, that would solve the problem by redrawing the data after the mouse button is released, although I am really curious why is the click blocking the UI thread. I also developed a similar program in Python (pyqtgraph), but that one never freezes, no matter what I do. If I happen to find the solution, I will post it here as well.